Cosine similarity matrix with Pyspark MS Fabric SparkJob
I am having some issues while computing some cosine similarities for a product recommender. I have an article database containing 40k articles each of them with their description. I am trying to calculate the cosine similarity matrix for this  elements so that when any article is given the top N most similar according to the description can be retrieved.
I am developing this in Python and the code should be run in a Microsoft Azure Function. As you can imagine already given the size of the initial df this cannot be run on this platform (It runs out of memory as the cosine similarity that is outputted is more 8 GB in size alone).
With this is mind I have decided to take another approach, which is using Spark, more accurately, a Spark Job definition from Microsoft Fabric. I have been reviewing similar questions (as my Pyspark knowledge is extremely limited) like this one: Calculating cosine similarity in Pyspark Dataframe, but I'm struggling to make the code work in my situation.
Trying to tackle problems one by one I have realized my code doesn't even get to the cosine similarity calculation (or at least not all of it) as my spark job gets frozen when attempting the crossjoin of matrices and I am unable to check what the exact issue is from the stderr logs.
I know my starting df of 40k rows is quite big and that this implies a 40k x 40k cos sim matrix but I tried this operation with plain python on a Google Collab notebook and it was able to calculate it in around 10 mins (It is true that I had to use the TPU backend as the normal CPU one also crashes after consuming the standard memory -12GB-).
At this point I'm thinking either:
-MS Fabric SparkJobs are also not a valid tool for my needs here as they offer a "weak/capped" version of spark.
-My Pyspark code clearly has something that is incorrect and causing the Spark executor to be decommissioned wrongly.
I need some help finding in which scenario I am (and if on the second how to improve the code).
Let me share some code.
This is the Python code that for the same task actually works on a TPU Collab notebook (using sklearn imports):
    articulos = articulos[['article_id','product_code', 'detail_desc']]
    articulos_unicos = articulos.drop_duplicates(subset=['product_code'])
    articulos_final = articulos_unicos.dropna(subset=['detail_desc'])
    articulos_final = articulos_final.reset_index(drop=True)

    count = CountVectorizer(stop_words='english')
    count_matrix = count.fit_transform(articulos_final['detail_desc'])
    count_matrix = count_matrix.astype(np.float32)

    similitud_coseno = cosine_similarity(count_matrix, count_matrix)
    

    np.fill_diagonal(similitud_coseno, -1)

    top_5_simart = []

    
    for i in range(similitud_coseno.shape[0]):
        top_indices = np.argpartition(similitud_coseno[i], -5)[-5:] 
        sorted_top_indices = top_indices[np.argsort(-similitud_coseno[i, top_indices])] 
        top_5_simart.append(sorted_top_indices.tolist())

    with open('top_5_simart.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(top_5_simart, f)

On the other hand this is the Pyspark code I am trying to implement:
    # Selecting the necessary columns
    articulos = articulos.select("article_id", "product_code", "detail_desc")

    # Removing duplicates
    articulos = articulos.dropDuplicates(["product_code"]).dropna(subset=["detail_desc"])

    # Tokenizing the description text
    tokenizer = Tokenizer(inputCol="detail_desc", outputCol="words")
    articulos_tokenized = tokenizer.transform(articulos)

    # Removing stopwords
    remover = StopWordsRemover(inputCol="words", outputCol="filtered_words")
    articulos_clean = remover.transform(articulos_tokenized)

    # Generating the feature column with CountVectorizer
    vectorizer = CountVectorizer(inputCol="filtered_words", outputCol="features")
    vectorizer_model = vectorizer.fit(articulos_clean)
    articulos_final = vectorizer_model.transform(articulos_clean)
    articulos_final = articulos_final.select("article_id","features")
    print(articulos_final.dtypes)
    print(articulos_final.schema)
    
    # Using crossJoin to obatain all the pairwise values for the cosine sim
    articulos_final2 = articulos_final.withColumnRenamed("article_id","article_id2").withColumnRenamed("features","features2")
    articulos_final_cos_sim = articulos_final.crossJoin(articulos_final2)
    articulos_final.unpersist()
    articulos_final2.unpersist()
    articulos_final_cos_sim.write.mode('overwrite').format('delta').save(cspath)
    
    '''
    # Realizar el crossJoin para obtener todas las combinaciones de pares de filas
    articulos_final_cos_sim = (
    articulos_final.alias("a")
    .crossJoin(articulos_final.alias("b"))
    .withColumn(
        "dot_product", 
        F.col("a.features").dot(F.col("b.features"))  # Producto punto de los vectores
        )
    .withColumn(
        "norm_a", 
        F.expr("a.features.norm(2)")  # Norma L2 del vector 'a'
        )
    .withColumn(
        "norm_b", 
        F.expr("b.features.norm(2)")  # Norma L2 del vector 'b'
        )
    .withColumn(
        "cosine_similarity",
        F.col("dot_product") / (F.col("norm_a") * F.col("norm_b"))  # Similitud coseno
        )
    )

    # Eliminar las columnas innecesarias
    articulos_final_cos_sim = articulos_final_cos_sim.drop("dot_product", "norm_a", "norm_b")

    # Agrupar para construir la matriz de similitud
    articulos_final_cos_sim = articulos_final_cos_sim.groupBy("a.article_id").pivot("b.article_id").sum("cosine_similarity")

    # Guardar los resultados
    articulos_final_cos_sim.write.mode('overwrite').format('delta').save(testpath2)


    
    # Filtrar para obtener los 5 artículos más similares para cada uno
    windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("article_id").orderBy(F.col("cosine_similarity").desc())

    top_5_simart = articulos_final_cos_sim.withColumn("rank", F.row_number().over(windowSpec)).filter(F.col("rank") <= 5)

    # Guardar los resultados en formato JSON
    top_5_simart.write.mode('overwrite').json(Top5SimartPath)
    '''


As you can see the last part of the code is commented since (after a lot of attempts) this code didn't give me any errors that made the execution fail, it simply took forever to execute. The active part of the code only does the cross join but doesn't do any of the calculations yes, as I mentioned it is stuck forever.
If needed I can also provide the stderror logs of Spark.

Cross join is working fine, commented part running long time and fails?

Also F.col("a.features").dot(F.col("b.features") here it raise error column object is not callable. check the code once properly.

Is below provided approach working for you?

The cross join gives you 1,60,00,00,000 rows
and you doing group by on it, which does many shuffling and takes more time and memory.
So, my idea is to do partition before join and use more number of nodes/workers and cores.
Here is the sample code i used in my spark environment with 40k random data rows.
dot_udf = F.udf(lambda  v1, v2: float(v1.dot(v2)), DoubleType())
# Define UDF to compute the L2 norm of a vector
norm_udf = F.udf(lambda  v: float(v.norm(2)), DoubleType())

a = articulos_final.repartition(40000,"article_id")
b = articulos_final.repartition(40000,"article_id")

articulos_final_cos_sim = (
    a.alias("a")
    .crossJoin(b.alias("b"))
    .withColumn("dot_product", dot_udf(F.col("a.features"), F.col("b.features")))  # Dot product
    .withColumn("norm_a", norm_udf(F.col("a.features")))  # L2 norm of vector 'a'
    .withColumn("norm_b", norm_udf(F.col("b.features")))  # L2 norm of vector 'b'
    .withColumn(
        "cosine_similarity",
        F.col("dot_product") / (F.col("norm_a") * F.col("norm_b"))  # Cosine similarity
    )
)

final1 = articulos_final_cos_sim.groupBy("a.article_id").pivot("b.article_id").sum("cosine_similarity")

final1.select("article_id","39848").sort("39848",ascending=False).show(5)

Here, for the article 39848 the top 5 similar documents is calculated, which took around 29 mins to run, having 10 workers, 16 cores in each total 160 cores.
Output:
+----------+------------------+
|article_id|             39848|
+----------+------------------+
|     39848|               1.0|
|     20088|0.3333333333333333|
|      6257|            0.3125|
|     21005|0.2886751345948129|
|     29086|0.2886751345948129|
+----------+------------------+
only showing top 5 rows


and

In your fabric environment increase the compute size and run above code which is repartitioning to 40000. You adjust this number according to your compute size and number of cores.
It can be 160 also, for each core one partition task.
Also, do persist if you do operations frequently.

Hi JayashankarGS!
Sorry for the really late response. I have been going though very rough personal times which drove me away from this temporarily.
Interestingly enough since I didnt cancel the job it eventually did finish (after 1 and half days).
Also trying with a smaller sample I did realize the code was wrong indeed since, as you mention, you cant call F.col to do the vector operations. The reason I did this was to try to avoid using UDF since they technically slow down the execution.

I checked the spark documentation and saw that there are native methods on sparse vectors for norm and dot product though I clearly fail to understand why I simply can implement them.
As for your solution I will proceed to try as soon as I can but im wondering, how does repartition actually work? I understand that to calculate the cosine similarity you need all the data, you cant just chop the matrix into smaller ones and then join them right?

Also, just out of curiosity ( I just want to broaden my knowledge here), how does a "normal" (quote because its the TPU environment) python notebook on collab succesfully manage this task in basically less time than a tool specifically desgined for Big Data like Spark?
Many thanks for the help! Marked as solution (pending the testing on my side but definitely looks good)

Groupby and pivoting 40k rows these two operations making things slow. groupby does shuffling which moves the data between executors, when you do partition shuffling doesn't happens and runs faster. partition doen't chop the matrix it just keeps the article_id in single partitions.

In your python notebook you are using in built packages which are optimized, but here we are using raw dataframe and doing calculation. If you run the same python code in databricks it still works as how it works in collab notebooks with sklearn import.

Another interesting piece of information, thanks for that! I did hear previously from Databricks and its very good performance but they prices they have are completley out my league. Still its good to know that there are this type of solutions out there.
Many thanks again!
